# UIView move after CGAffineTransformMakeRotation

Tags: objective-c, uiview, rotation

I have to do a rotation on UIview and after to move it on parent UIview but I cannot calculate the destination points because the frame was modified by the rotation.

How can I recalculate these points to place correctly my uiview ???

EDIT :

Here an example what i try : http://s21.postimg.org/cvptbdxwz/circle.jpg?noCache=1373268522

1* Rotation of 90°
2* Move to the edge of the circle.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Post some code may be? You should not use frame property directly on a view that have transform set

Comment: Rotate + translate? Maybe translate + rotate? What are you really after? [You can read more in my post here about combinations about rotation and translation](http://ronnqvi.st/translate-rotate-translate/)

Comment: After the rotation, i not able to calcute the right (x,y) to position the element on my parent frame with transform.
I can't translate after because it's ugly to the animation.
PS:sorry to my bad english

Comment: I added a example of what i try.